# c++ store sum of a variable of an array of class

Tags: c++

I have a class that holds an array of another class. The class needs to store a sum of a variable of the classes in the array. The classes stored in the array have their own extensive logic to update the order size.

What is the best way to ensure the class always has an accurate sum of variable of the objects in array at all times?
Is there a design pattern/best practice to ensure this?

Both classes are doing many other things so there is a vast code base. I can make changes within the classes but not the enviroment i-e cant create inheritance relationship between classes and etc.

```
 class OrderManager {
   int m_totalOrderSize; //needs to store the sum of all order sizes
   std::vector<Order> Orders;  //the array with the size variable.        
 }

 class Order {
   int size; //this size variable is updated in many ways in this class.
   /*
    This is one of the function that updates size. 
    How do I make sure whenever size gets updated here, the 
    OrderManager.m_totalOrderSize also gets updated accordingly.
    */
   UpdateSize();
   ResetSize();
 }
```

Comment: If you're using arbitrary sized arrays, you probably want to use a Standard Library container. If you want to keep an accurate count of things, make sure all your data is private and have gatekeeper functions to access it.

Comment: actually IA m using a vector, post edited.

Comment: `Class` with a capital `C` is not valid C++.

Comment: So long as that vector's not directly exposed you're in better shape. You'll need to trap on your insert, remove, or update functions to adjust your counts and totals accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pattern Observer to update the size in OrderManager class, each time one of its orders was updated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

In your case **Order** is a subject and **OrderManager** is the observer